# Scala Option[Future[T]] to Future[Option[T]]

Tags: scala, future

How can I convert `Option[Future[T]]` to `Future[Option[T]]` in scala?

I want to use it in:

```
val customerAddresses = for {
  a <- addressDAO.insert(ca.address) // Future[Address]
  ia <- ca.invoiceAddress.map(addressDAO.insert) // Option[Future[Address]]
} yield (a, ia) // Invalid value have to be two futures
```

Here signature insert method

```
def insert(address: Address): Future[Address]
```

`ca` is a CustomerData

```
case class CustomerData(address: Address, invoiceAddress: Option[Address])
```

Comment: So `a <- addressDAO.insert(ca.address)` returns a `Future[Option]` ?

Comment: Could you specify signatures of your methods?

Comment: I'd use `.sequence` from `scalaz/cats` with https://github.com/milessabin/si2712fix-plugin - but that would probably be overkill.

Comment: Public note to future self: every time I try cats's `.sequence` for this it doesn't work until I realize there are conflicting implicits in scope, so if you move `import cats.implicits._` directly above the call to `.sequence` then it works.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

def f[A](x: Option[Future[A]])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[A]] = 
  x match {
     case Some(f) => f.map(Some(_))
     case None    => Future.successful(None)
  }
```

Examples:

```
scala> f[Int](Some(Future.successful(42)))
res3: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[Int]] = Success(Some(42))

scala> f[Int](None)
res4: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@c88a337
```

Answer (score 16):

If you have cats as a dependency in your application, the most beautiful way would be to use `traverse`

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

val customerAddresses = for {
  a  <- addressDAO.insert(ca.address)                 // Future[Address]
  ia <- ca.invoiceAddress.traverse(addressDAO.insert) // Future[Option[Address]]
} yield (a, ia)
```

Comment: this is gorgeous

Comment: you save my day

Answer (score 12):

The standard library does provide the methods to use Future.sequence on an Option, unfortunately you have to plumb them together.

Either as a quick method:

```
def swap[M](x: Option[Future[M]]): Future[Option[M]] =
    Future.sequence(Option.option2Iterable(x)).map(_.headOption)
```

Note I found the implicit `Option.option2Iterable` was already in scope for me. So you may not need to provide it, reducing the code down to `Future.sequence(x).map(_.headOption)`

Or you may prefer an extension method:

```
implicit class OptionSwitch[A](f: Option[Future[A]]) {
    import scala.concurrent.Future

    def switch: Future[Option[A]] = Future.sequence(Option.option2Iterable(f))
      .map(_.headOption)
  }


val myOpt = Option(Future(3))
myOpt.switch
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is another solution:

```
def swap[T](o: Option[Future[T]]): Future[Option[T]] =
  o.map(_.map(Some(_))).getOrElse(Future.successful(None))
```

The trick is to convert `Option[Future[T]]` into `Option[Future[Option[T]]]` which is easy, and then extract the value from that `Option`.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a list (or any `TraversableOnce`) of futures and want a single future for computing the whole list, you use `Future.sequence` or `Future.traverse`. You can think of an Option like a list of 1 or 0 elements but since is technically not a list you have to go for a little conversion in this case. Anyway, this is a code that does it normally:

```
  val optionFuture:Option[Future[String]] = ???

  val futureOption:Future[Option[String]] = Future.sequence(optionFuture.toIterable).map(_.headOption)
```

In you example use better `Future.traverse`:

```
  val customerAddresses = for {
    a <- addressDAO.insert(ca.address) // Future[Address]
    ia <- Future.traverse(ca.invoiceAddress.toIterable)(addressDAO.insert).map(_.headOption) // Future[Option[Address]]
  } yield CustomerData(a, ia) // Types OK
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val customerAddresses = for {
  a <- addressDAO.insert(ca.address) // Future[Address]
  ia <- ca.invoiceAddress.map(x => addressDAO.insert(x).map(_.map(k => Some(k))).getOrElse(Future.successful(None)))
} yield (a, ia)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply using [Dumonad](https://github.com/dumonad/dumonad)

```
import io.github.dumonad.dumonad.Implicits._
futureOfOption.dummed
```