# Is it possible to change monadic sequence?

Tags: scala, monads

***The problem***: I have the following `Future[Option[T]]` monad and I would like to apply scalaz Monad Transformer `OptionT` to it. Cos I'm interested only in Optional result.

***Question***: Is it possible to produce `Option[Future[T]]` from `Future[Option[T]]` preserving the semantic?

Comment: Note that your question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226203/scala-optionfuturet-to-futureoptiont), only with reversed direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.sequence`:

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._, ...

scala> val a: Future[Option[Int]] = Future(None)
a: Future[Option[Int]] = Future(Success(None))

scala> val b = a.sequence
b: Option[Future[Int]] = None
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a shorter way to get `OptionT` from `Future[Option[T]]`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. (This has nothing to do with monad transformer)