# How to convert Future[Option[A]] to Future[A]

Tags: scala, future

I am new to Scala and wanted to know how can we convert `Future[Option[A]]` to `Future[A]`

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/38226646/14746858

Answer (score 5):

Since an `Option[A]` might be `None`, if you want to convert it to an `A`, the most direct way is to use the `.getOrElse(value)` method, where you need to provide a default value of type `A` to use if the option itself doesn't have one.

```
val opt1 = Some(3)
opt1.getOrElse(5) //returns 3

val opt2 = None
opt2.getOrElse(5) //returns 5
```

Then, if you have a `Future[Option[A]]`, you want to do this in the `.map` method of the future:

```
val futureOpt: Future[Option[Int]] = Future{ Some(3) }
val future: Future[Int] = futureOpt.map{opt => opt.getOrElse(5)}
```

Answer (score 3):

An `Option[A]` can either be `Some[A]` or `None`. The `Some[A]` case is simple, you can just get A from it. But what about the `None` case, you can either provide a default value or consider it a failure.

Using a default value,

```scala
val aDefault: A = ...

val aFuture1 = aOptionFuture.map({
  case Some(a) => a
  case None => aDefault
})

// or

val aFuture2 = aOptionFuture.map(_.getOrElse(aDefault))
```

Consider a failure,

```scala
val aFuture3 = aOptionFuture.flatMap({
  case Some(a) => Future.successful(a)
  case None=> Future.failed(new Exception("computed a None"))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val optFuture: Future[Option[Int]] = Future(Some(3))
optFuture.map {
  case Some(v) => v
  case None => throw new RuntimeException("<some-exception>")
}
```

Or

```
optFuture.map(_.getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException("<some-exception>")))
```